# Django Model Form DateTimeField form validation error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am a django noobie, I am having problem with  models Datetimefield. When I am using model form to fill the date time it's showing pleae enter valid date.

Here is My files

Views.py

```
def Report_incident(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form=IncidentReportForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        report=form.save(commit=False)
        report.user=request.user
        report.save()
        return HttpResponse('Success')
else:
    form=IncidentReportForm()
context={'form':form}
return render(request, 'Assginment/report.html',context)
```

Here is Model Form forms.py

```
class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime-local'
    
class IncidentReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    incident_cat=(
        ('Environmental incident','Environmental incident'),
        ('Injury/Illness','Injury/Illness'),
        ('Property Damage','Propert Damage'),
        ('Vehicle','Vehicle'),
        )
    time=forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateTimeInput(),
                                 input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'])
    incident_type=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=incident_cat,
                                           widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model=Incident
        fields=('location','description','incident_location',
                'severity','cause','action_taken')
```

Here is my Models.py part

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    location_choices=(
        ('Corporate Headoffice','Corporate Headoffice'),
        ('Operations Department','Operations Department'),
        ('Work Station','Work Station'),
        ('Marketing Division','Marketing Division'),
        )
    severity_choices=(
        ('Mild','Mild'),
        ('Moderate','Moderate'),
        ('Severe','Severe'),
        ('Fatal','Fatal'),
        )
    location=models.CharField(choices=location_choices,max_length=300,
                              default='Corporate Headoffice')
    description=models.TextField()
    time=models.DateTimeField()
    incident_location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    severity=models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=severity_choices,
                              default='Mild')
    cause=models.TextField()
    action_taken=models.TextField()
    incident_type=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    reporter=models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='reporter')
```

My template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Report An Incident {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Report Incident">
    </form>
    <p>{{ cd }}</p>
    {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am guessing that the problem is in formate of date time please explain me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your input format at '*IncidentReportForm*' is ***'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'***.
Django database can't accept this format of a date. So, you should change '**input_formats**' to ***'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'***
I think it will work!